# Changing from CharField to IntegerField - Postgres Column data type hasn't changed Django

Tags: python, django, postgresql, sqldatatypes, django-migrations

So I switched from sqlite to postgresql for production of my django reviews website- but due to psql being strongly typed, I'm having errors with my code

```
LINE 1: ...Col1, (AVG(((("boards_review"."move_in_condition" + "boards_...
                                                             ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

So I figured I could change the type by changing my CharFields to IntegerFields to change the type to int... like so

```
 move_in_condition = models.CharField(max_length=5,choices=RATING_CHOICES, blank=False, default='5')
 treatment = models.CharField(max_length=5, choices=RATING_CHOICES, blank=False, default ="5")
 response_speed = models.CharField(max_length=5, choices=RATING_CHOICES, blank=False, default ="5")
 maintenance_quality = models.CharField(max_length=5, choices=RATING_CHOICES, blank=False, default ="5")
```

to

```
    move_in_condition = models.IntegerField(choices=RATING_CHOICES, blank=False, default=5)
    treatment = models.IntegerField(choices=RATING_CHOICES, blank=False, default =5)
    response_speed = models.IntegerField(choices=RATING_CHOICES, blank=False, default =5)
    maintenance_quality = models.IntegerField(choices=RATING_CHOICES, blank=False, default =5)
```

with choices:

```
class Review(models.Model):
    RATING_CHOICES = (
        (1, '1'),
        (2, '2'),
        (3, '3'),
        (4, '4'),
        (5, '5'),
    )
```

But then i read somewhere that sql doesn't directly support changing a string column to an int column....So i'm still getting the same error. I tried deleting my db creating it new again, and I'm still getting the same exact error after migrating.

I believe this is the bit that is triggering the error

```
    def get_avg(self):
        return self.reviews.annotate(
            overall_rating = Sum(
                F('move_in_condition') + 
                F('treatment') + 
                F('response_speed') +
                F('maintenance_quality')
            )/4).aggregate(
                Avg('overall_rating'), 
                Avg('move_in_condition'),
                Avg('treatment'),
                Avg('response_speed'),
                Avg('maintenance_quality')
            )
```

But yeah I'm just trying to display several averages reviews of companies and such, and can't seem to figure it out after trying for a couple days. thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried casting your fields directly in the query?, just like that: ```Avg(int('your_field'))```

Comment: THis worked! thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a cast problem, so first you need to answer, ¿What is the data type that you really need? If choose CharField, you can cast your fields directly in the query, just like this:

`Avg(int('your_field'))`

Answer (score 0):

just added int() as manuel said!

```
    def get_avg(self):
        return self.reviews.annotate(
            overall_rating = Sum(int(
                F('move_in_condition') + 
                F('treatment') + 
                F('response_speed') +
                F('maintenance_quality')
            ))/4).aggregate(
                Avg('overall_rating'), 
                Avg('move_in_condition'),
                Avg('treatment'),
                Avg('response_speed'),
                Avg('maintenance_quality')
            )
```

Comment: ..where do you add this... show inline with code. You may want to use "...snippet".. to show only short peace of code but keep in mind people can follow where its put. (End of Review).